# Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equation - $x$'s and $y$'s all over the place, integer coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have come across the following differential equation:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^{2}+125x^{2}+42x^{3}+12xy-4x^{2}y}{xy}$$

It quite possibly has no closed-form solution but I would appreciate any insights if possible. I hope I put the equation in properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^2+125x^2+42x^3+12xy-4x^2y}{xy}$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^2}{x}+(12-4x)y+42x^2+125x$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $y=xu$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$

$\therefore xu\left(x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u\right)=\dfrac{x^2u^2}{x}+(12-4x)xu+42x^2+125x$

$x^2u\dfrac{du}{dx}+xu^2=xu^2+(12-4x)xu+42x^2+125x$

$x^2u\dfrac{du}{dx}=(12-4x)xu+42x^2+125x$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{12}{x}-4\right)u+42+\dfrac{125}{x}$

Comment: That's very helpful - I've run into some problems with the original question, this should solve it!

Answer (score 0):

The first things you should attempt are to see if it is seperable or exact.  It's not seperable (you can't get all the x's with the dx and all the y's with the dy).   So, to see if it's exactly, we put it into standard form ($Mdx+NdY=C$)  and see if $M_y=N_x$  So, in standard form, we have $(y^2+125x^2+42x^3+12xy-4x^2y)dx+(-xy)dy=0$   So,  $M_y=2y+12x-4x^2$,  $N_x=-y$,  we are not exact.   Then one would try to come up with an integrating factor, some function $\mu(x,y)$ such that if we multiplied through in standard form we would be exact...unfortunately, not only is this not always possible, there's often no solution.

Beyond that, there are techniques to examine linearization and equilibrium, but I'm just taking that course now myself :).

Comment: I took differential equations as an engineering course years ago but this never made any sense to me: It is known that $ dy/dx $ is just a notation and not an actual "division" of infinitesimal values. If it is so; how are we allowed to treat $ dy/dx $ as a real division and multiply both sides with $ dx $?

Comment: The short answer is:  They aren't actually fractions and real division, but there's abstract and complicated math that proves that we can treat them as if they were and it's still valid.  The long answer is, I'm only in my second year of grad school and haven't seen that complicated math myself.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, or at least part of it. The above comes from a system of differential equations (two of them but each with respect to a third variable) - and I thought I had simplified it (!). Anyway, I managed to rearrange them in terms of the general solution not involving the third variable, and used the Lambert W function to come up with a differential equation in the variables I needed (same two as above). Now I'll use Euler's Method or something similar to solve it numerically. If it all works out, I'll post the solution when I've got my head around the MathJaX...